Acer monitor suspends after 10 minutes of playing a Steam game
I recently bought a game on Steam. My computer's fast enough for it, but the monitor turns off about every 10 minutes. I then have to reboot the computer to turn it back on, thereby losing all my progress.
I tried checking the suspend settings in the system settings and in the monitor settings, but I couldn't find anything that had to do with suspending in the monitor settings. All I could find in the system settings was suspending after x minutes of inactivity, which was already set to never.
I have no idea what model my monitor is, all I know is it's Acer. I have an AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT and an Intel Core i3-10105F processor. My OS is Ubuntu 24.04. My kernel version is Linux 6.8.0-41-generic.

Maybe a thermal problem. In your original posting, add the output of sensors (from the lm-sensors package).

I have one system that I really struggled with keeping the screen from blanking. It's a older HP desktop connected to a large screen TV. Like you I set all the screensaver / power / monitor settings appropriately and yet the screen still blanked. Finally I found these two commands (unfortunately I don't remember where) that fixed it. I have them in a script and run it automatically at boot. The commands are xset -dpms and xset s off. Give it a try.

@OrganicMarble thanks, I'll try that. Do you by chance, know what the command does? In general, I like to know what a command does before I run it

@SmallCoder12 Yeah, I would have written a real answer if I could have found that in my notes. (also if I could guarantee it work work in your situation). I'll see what I can find.

@SmallCoder12 here is an arch linux page about it, probably where I learned about it https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling  Looks like it's "Disable DPMS and prevent screen from blanking " although they give a single command where I have two.

@OrganicMarble I just tried running xset -dpms and xset s off in the terminal. xset -dpms returns server does not have extension for -dpms option. Ignoring this, I ran the next command, tried opening a different steam game and... still blanked out. I'm skipping processing the Vulcan shaders, could that cause this?

Could you be running on wayland? xset only works on xorg. I have no experience with wayland. If you get that message, xset isn't going to work for you.

@OrganicMarble I switched to xorg, re-ran the commands, and it still blanked out for me after about four minutes
